# Typedef to a double array of ints

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, typedef

I am trying to learn about an implementation of some code that uses a typedef to a double array and also uses pointers and I am having some difficulty understanding the code and details on how the code works and what types the variables are and what points to what.

I have tried playing around with different implementations and trying to understand how it works but the results I have gotten have been not what I have expected.
Heres some code I tried to test:

```
typedef int array[2][6];
array *arr;
arr = (array*)malloc(sizeof(array));
*arr[0][0]=2;
*arr[0][1]=4;

*arr[1][0]=3;
*arr[1][1]=5;
printf("line 1: %d %d\nline 2: %d %d\n",*arr[0][0],*arr[1][0],*arr[0][1],*arr[1][1]);
int *in = (int*) ((*arr)[0]);
printf("in = %d\n",in[1]); // results are unexpected
```

The code that I am actually looking at is for a ping pong buffer and is  (simplified) as follows:

```
int buffer_count = 2; // 2 ping pong buffers
int sample_size = 15;
typedef int PingPong_t[buffer_count][sample_size];

PingPong_t *inputstream;

// logic goes here to determine pingpong_idx
int pingpong_idx = 0; // I believe this is to choose the first or second buffer

int *pcmIn = (int*)((*inputstream)[pingpong_idx]);

// do processing
```

I expect that pcmIn is an integer array of the current ping or pong buffer, but I am having trouble proving that to myself or I am just unsure what the datatypes actually are and what it is actually doing.

A good question I might have is, what is the type of inputstream? Is it correct to say that inputstream is a pointer to a double array of integers? Or is inputstream a double array of integer pointers?

Then what would be the type of pcmIn?

Comment: Why are the results in the first code block unexpected? It prints `in = 2` on my machine.

Comment: When I changed the index to 1 it prints unexpected results

Comment: Adding a tag for the programming language might make things a little clearer.

Comment: All of the `*arr[x][y]` expressions should be `(*arr)[x][y]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down.

`typedef int PingPong_t[buffer_count][sample_size];`

This will make `PingPong_t` represent a 2D array of integers.
So, you can have

`PingPong_t p = {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}};`

Then, we declare a pointer to this type as

`PingPong_t *inputstream;`

which means that `inputstream` is a pointer to whatever `PingPong_t` represents. It is not an array, not an array of pointers, just a pointer.

Since PingPong_t essentially means `int x[2][15]`, `inpustream` will mean `int (*y)[2][15]`.

Suppose we had something like

`inputstream = &p;`

Then, `inputstream` will **point** to the 2D array that is p. A custom pointer of type 2-dimensional (2 x 15) `int` array.

So, `inputstream` is `int (*)[2][15]` and `p` is `int [2][15]`.

Now, playing it further, let us suppose we were to increment `inputstream`.

Incrementing a pointer will add the size of the type it points to.

So, in our case incrementing `inpustream` adds `sizeof(int)*2*15` i.e. 120 (my machine has 4-byte `int`). Note that it does not add `sizeof(int)` here as its base type is not `int` but a 2D array of `int`s.

Finally, `pcmIn` is an `int` pointer (which can be thought of as a 1D array here), we are assigning like this

`int *pcmIn = (int*)((*inputstream)[pingpong_idx]);`

which fetches the first row (`pingpong_idx`) of the 2D array that `inputstream` points to, and assigns it to `pcmIn`.

Furthermore, you are getting unexpected results in your example above as you are assigning to the array in wrong manner. Since `arr` is a pointer to 2D array, you assign a value to an element like this
`(*arr)[0][1]=4;`
and not like this
`*arr[0][1]=4;`.

The latter will mean that `arr` is a 2D array of pointers and you are basically setting the value of `[0][1]`th pointer to 4, which is not what you had planned.

`arr` is not a 2D array and so `arr[0][1]` will mean the adding `sizeof(int)*15` to the value of `arr`, and `*arr[0][1]` is basically getting/setting value at that address. In effect, the `[0][1]`th value is still uninitialized.

But, then how does `*arr[0][0]=2;` and `printf("in = %d\n",in[0]);` work?

Because, doing `*arr[0][0]=2;` will set the value of `[0][0]`th element to 2.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. So then its correct to say that PingPong_t is of the type 2 dimensional integer array (2x15). And inputstream is of the type pointer to a 2 dimensional integer array (2x15). So *inputstream is (not a pointer) but the actual 2 dimensional integer array itself.

Comment: Yes, `(*inputstream)` will be the actual 2D array.